# please remove suggested synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

A while back I suggested that the [tz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tz) tag be merged as a synonym of the [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone) tag, but I recently realized that it can be useful for questions specifically about the `tz` environment variable.

I've updated the [tz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tz) tag wiki, and retagged several questions, but I don't see any way to remove my tag synonym suggestion.

Please remove the suggested synonym for the [tz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tz) tag from the [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone) tag, [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/synonyms).  Thanks.